# Jest, use different jest.mock for different tests

Tags: jestjs

I need to use a different mock value of a function in 2 different test.

Currently I have this code (part of it):

```
import soap from 'soap';

const client = {
  feeLookupAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(feeLookupAsyncResponse))
};

jest.mock('soap', () => ({
  createClientAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(client))
}));

describe('functions.feelookup', () => {
  it('try to createClientAsync succesfully', async () => {
    // here I have a test where I need that createClientAsync resolves correctly the promise
    const response = await handler(event);
    // this handler use the function createClientAsync
    
    // and it works ok
  });

  it('try to createClientAsync but fails', async () => {

    // Promise.reject(new Error('ops')))
    
    // here I have a test where I need that createClientAsync the promise rejects
    const response = await handler(event);
    // this handler use the function createClientAsync
    
    // So I need that `jest.mock('soap')` be like this:
    
    jest.mock('soap', () => ({
      createClientAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error('ops')))
    }));

    // And then the test will be ok
  });
});
```

But my problem is it doesn't work if I put those `jest.mock('soap', () => ({` definitions inside each `it()`. if I put it above the `describe` works ok but only for the first case and not for the second of course where I need the opposite (to rejects).

How can I use both mocked values, one for the first test and the other for the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jest.mock` inside a test cannot affect already imported module, in order for it to take effect a module needs to be re-imported. It's unneeded in this case because only method implementation is changed, this can be handled by Jest spies.

Mocked methods shouldn't be assigned to long-living objects as `... = jest.fn()`, this prevents Jest from preforming mock restore and may result in cross-test contamination for test-specific mocks.

If a method wasn't mocked before, it can be made Jest spy:

```
jest.spyOn(soap, 'createClientAsync').mockImplementation(...);
```

If a method was mocked before, the implementation can be changed with:

```
soap.createClientAsync.mockImplementation(...);
```

For test-specific mocks it's preferable to use `Once` methods where possible, this prevents cross-test contamination:

```
soap.createClientAsync.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('ops'));
```

Comment: would you then say that, mocking a module or a module method for several/all test files, one should use `jest.mock`. We could consider it as a _"long-living mock"_.
On the other hand, mocking a module or a module method for a single file or test case should be mocked with `jest.spyOn`. We could consider it as a _"short-living mock"_?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. jest.mock is for one test file (suite), unless you use some kind of helpers that allow to reuse it between multiple files. jest.mock can be used per test or several tests (beforeEach) but this requires to re-import the whole module hierarchy that depend on it. spyOn is short-lived only when mockRestore is used, it's a good practice to do this for all mocks with related Jest config

Comment: I see, thanks! I had a hard time finding any resource on when to use `jest.mock` vs `jest.spyOn`. The docs can be somehow mythical at times.

Would you still use `jest.mock` for a whole test file(suite) over `jest.spyOn`?

Comment: @Tanckom Definitely. I don't think it's often to have a module that needs to be mocked in one test and not another within one suite. Most times you'd need to change the implementation of mocked module export at most, and it's doable with jest.mock

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I solved with this:

```
(soap.createClientAsync as jest.Mock) = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error('ops')));
```

In the test where I need to be rejected the promise, I overwrite soap.createClientAsync with that definition. Not convinced at all of my solution.